# I have a master degree in Chemistry, experienced in Programming but don't have any degree in CS

Tags: usa, working-visas, h1-visa, skilled-migration

Is it possible for me to apply for a USA h1b visa as a Programmer? Do I have any chances to actually get such kind of visa if formally I can apply (and as I understand formally I can).
I mean  if they [company] have additional problems while I don't have special degree (that's why they'll prefere somebody else who is less experienced but has a degree)?

Comment: You don't apply; a company or university that wants to hire you applies.

Comment: Yes, I know that but if they [company] have additional problems while I don't have special degree (that's why they'll prefere somebody else who is less experienced but has a degree)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

H1b qualification requirements from the [USCIS website](https://www.uscis.gov/eir/visa-guide/h-1b-specialty-occupation/understanding-h-1b-requirements):

> - A bachelor’s degree or higher degree or its equivalent is normally the minimum requirement for the particular position;
> - The degree requirement is common for this position in the industry, or the job is so complex or unique that it can only be performed by someone with at least a bachelor's degree in a field related to the position;
> - The employer normally requires a degree or its equivalent for the position; or
> - The nature of the specific duties is so specialized and complex that the knowledge required to perform the duties is usually associated with the attainment of a bachelor's or higher degree.

So, they don't specifically require *you* to have a bachelors degree in the field you'd be working in, but it should normally be the case that a person filling this role would have one.
It's then up to the company to decide *if* they're prepared to employ you and sponsor your visa even though you don't have a relevant degree.
It would probably help if you could somehow leverage your chemistry degree by looking for programming jobs in the chemical industry or even jobs which would directly fit your chemistry qualifications.

Answer (score 4):

If you find a company that wants to hire you, they will apply for that visa.

The main point is not what qualifications you have in detail, but that *they cannot find equivalently qualified resources on the US market*. Although there is some supposed  weakness in the execution of these rules, that is all that should count.

What you should look at is if there will be jobs that you qualify well for and not many US people qualify. The exact title of your education is of little importance.